# IOS Firebase Crashlytics issues

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I followed the firebase crashlytics [procedure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started).

I created console project, I installed

```
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'

[FIRApp configure];
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
[[Fabric sharedSDK] setDebug: YES];
```

But I never get the crash list in firebase.

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. Make sure Xcode's debugger is disconnected when you're causing crashes. Xcode’s debugger prevents us from capturing crash reports, but if you disconnect the debugger, then we’ll be able to capture them. Note that if your device is plugged into your machine, the debugger can still get in the way. To make sure Xcode’s debugger is disconnected:
Launch the Simulator.
Hit Stop in Xcode.
Launch your app in the Simulator and cause a crash.
Hit Run in Xcode.

Comment: I connected in device and debug the xcode but not getting crash in firebase.

Comment: Can you share the console output after causing the crash and relaunching the app?

Comment: Finally i fixed the issue that the itunes dsym file added in firebase i got the successfully crash result.